# Intellij - Reformat Code - Insert whitespace between // and the comment-text?

Tags: intellij-idea, coding-style, ide, reformat, reformatting

I am working with another human being on project from that the professor expects to  have uniform code-style. We have written large separate junks of code on our own, in which one has written single line comments without a white-space between the single-line-comment-token and the other one has inserted a white-space. We are working with IntelliJ and have failed to find an option to enable the `Reformat Code` function, to insert a white-space.

**TLDR**:
Can you tell us how to convert comments from that to this in IntelliJ?

```
// This is a load bearing comment - don't dare to remove it
//This is a load bearing comment - don't dare to remove it!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a global search and replace (ctrl-shift-r on windows with default keyboard layout, or `Replace in Path` under the `Edit/Find` menu).

Check the regular expression option and enter `//(\S.*)` as the text to find and `// $1` as the replacement. Check the whole project option, and clear any file masks. You can single step through the replacements, or simply hit the `All Files` option.

Comment: Wonderful, your answer has helped me a lot. Thank you!